# How do I make Phantom.js cache resources like a normal browser?

Tags: phantomjs

Chrome doesn't re-download javascript files every request.  They cache it.

However, when my Phantom.js hits pages, it downloads the javascript every single time.  Is there a setting that can make this act like a browser?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PhantomJs already supports in-memory cache ; this means that if you browse multiple pages in side the same running instance, PhantomJs will not download resources already in the cache.

You could turn on disk cache ; this will store web resources (js, css, images, ...) in the physical disk.

This is controlled by a command line parameter :

- **disk-cache**=[true|false] enables disk cache (at desktop services cache storage location, default is false). Also accepted: [yes|no]
- **max-disk-cache-size**=size limits the size of disk cache (in KB).

From [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/8GYaXKmowj0), it seems to be stored under `%AppData%/Local/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/cache/http.` on windows.

Comment: I think PhantomJS's ambiguous wording "at desktop services cache storage location, default is false" was not supposed to mean "the default is false if and only if some other option has set the cache to the 'desktop services cache storage location' (wherever that is), otherwise the default is true".  Rather, they meant the default is always false, and, if set to true, the (default) location is the 'desktop services cache storage location'.  I would have used a semicolon instead of a comma to disambiguate this.  As PhantomJS is no longer maintained, I can no longer raise that as a minor issue.

Comment: I did the same, but for some reason, it is not caching it and keep on requesting the resource files. :(