# Keep phantomjs cache

Tags: php, caching, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have a php script that scrapes the web and inserts the scraped data into a database.
The php script uses Phantomjs as a tool to scrape web pages.
The php script scrapes web pages on a specific domain.
for example:
www.example.com/firstFolder
www.example.com/secondFolder
and so on
My problem is that phantomjs doesn't keep cache of previous web pages that it has already requested during the script, and instead it just re-downloads them over again.
My guess is that phantomjs doesn't cache previous web pages that it loaded, because i call phantomjs from the php script as an external program each time i need to scrape a certain web page.

```
$response = shell_exec('phantomjs getWebPage.js');
```

And since i recall phantomjs as an external program each time, it probably doesn't have any memory of its previously scraped web pages.
I understand that if i were to run phantomjs in one instance, i could keep Phantomjs caching.
But i don't know how to do that without relinquishing entirely on php from my program.
So my question is this.
How can i keep phantomjs caching while still running my program in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Phantom.js cache resources like a normal browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822617/how-do-i-make-phantom-js-cache-resources-like-a-normal-browser)

Comment: i cannot seem to find %AppData%/Local/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/cache/http. on my computer

Comment: You have to first run PhantomJS with the disk-cache option. Are you on windows?

Comment: thank you.I ran with the --disk-cache=true option and now i can see the folders. So now, how can i verify that Phantomjs is loading resources from the cache?

Comment: You should be able to register to `page.onResourceReceived` and check if 304 status codes are shown.

Comment: I created a practice page on http://need4bit.com/phantomjsPractice/. I ran the program with --disk-cache=true just like u said. but i get the status code 200 for http://need4bit.com/images/bgimg.jpg.

Comment: Have you checked that the image in question is actually in the cache? I'm not entirely sure what is cached by PhantomJS.

Comment: yes i have in the directory AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS\cache\data7\7 a file "21nd0ol7.d" that has the same size exactly as the image 'http://need4bit.com/images/bgimg.jpg'. Maybe the problem is that the folder 'AppData' for me is a hidden folder and therefore phantomjs has no reading permisions on the directory?

Comment: I just tried it with your page and you can check that it is cached by timing the execution. The status stays at 200 for some reason. There is another more complicated programmatical solution for checking if a resource is retrieved from cache by checking the time taken between `onResourceRequested` and `onResourceReceived` for each resource.

Comment: Nope i just changed it to a visible directory and i still encounter the same problem :(

Comment: Yes you are right. I did some checks and when i ran the program with cache enabled my average 'time taken between onResourceRequested and onResourceReceived for each resource' was 41 milliseconds but when i ran with cache disabled my average time was 260 milliseconds. So why do i get the status code 200 if i load the resource from the cache. btw thank u very much for the help.

Comment: It's probably just another strange thing about PhantomJS.

Comment: Agreed this is a duplicate (and the PHP part was a red herring). But the comments are interesting - I wonder if it could be saved by rephrasing the question as "How can I confirm cache is working" or something like that?