# PhantomJS - store and include ETag in subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using `PhantomJS` as follows to retrieve and parse data from a website. This part is okay. Where I have a challenge is to store the ETag send by the server and include it in subsequent requests. How can I do this ?

My code is similar to the one below.

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
const url = 'https://example.com/'

let _ph, _page, _outObj;
phantom.create()
.then( (ph) => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then( (page) => {
    _page = page;
    return page.open(url);
}).then( (status) => {
    console.log(`Status: ${status}`);
    return _page.property('content');
}).then( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
}).catch( (e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: I don't think we can have control over ETag, it's a low-level thing that browser does automatically. Do you have proof it doesn't  work? There's an [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13677) discussing it works *somehow*. Also try [enabling disk cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856757/2715393)

Comment: the issue you have referenced above say's its working with `1.9.7`, but its not clear if ETag is correctly send in request. I like to check how it is in my case. Can you suggest how I could log the info on the HTTP request headers send as in the issue cited above in the form as below - `Going to http://localhost:9292/
  Request (#1) GET http://localhost:9292/
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2

  Response 200 (#1, stage "end")
  ETag: 76803
...`

Comment: Use a local dev proxy server like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)